# How to create list of web elements?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to make a list of web elements, but it can not seem to find the elements on the web page, although did worked 3 days ago and i can not find any changes in the web page.

this is the html code :

```html
<li id="wlg_41410" class="leagueWindow " dataid="41410">
    <h5 style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;" onclick="TodaysEventsLeagueWindow.minimizeRestoreClick(41410)">Europa League</h5>
    <div class="bet_type select" id="_bet_types"></div>
    <div class="bet_type lastscore  ">
        <h6>1X2 FT                                    </h6>
        <div class="types_bg">
            <!--[if IE]> <div id="IEroot"> <![endif]-->
            <div class="first_buttons_line">
            </div>
            <!--[if IE]> </div> <![endif]-->
            <div class="time"> 23/11 | 18:00 </div>
            <div class="bets ml">
            </div>
            <div class="time"> 23/11 | 20:00 </div>
            <div class="bets ml">
            </div>
            <div class="time"> 23/11 | 20:00 </div>
            <div class="bets ml">                
            </div>
            <div class="time"> 23/11 | 20:00 </div>
            <div class="bets ml">                
            </div>
            <div class="time"> 23/11 | 20:00 </div>
            <div class="bets ml">
            </div>
            <div class="clr"></div>
        </div>
    </div> <span class="x" onclick="TodaysEventsLeagueWindow.closeLeagueWindow(41410)"></span>
</li>
```

i am trying to make a list from the `<div class="bets ml"></div>` elements
but keep getting the `selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document` exception , as if selenium can't find the web element.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
import time

driver.get("https://www.luckia.es/apuestas")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("sbtechBC"))
eventos_de_hoy = driver.find_element_by_id("today_event_btn")
eventos_de_hoy.click()

ligi_len = len(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "leagueWindow "))))
print(ligi_len)
for index in range(ligi_len):        
        item = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "leagueWindow ")))[index]
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", item)
        nume_liga = item.find_element_by_tag_name("h5").text
        time.sleep(3)
        print('try', nume_liga)
        meci = item.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='bets ml']")
        print("there are", len(meci), "in one liga")
```

the reason for the `index` is that the iframe refreshes every 25 sec.

i also tried `meci = item.find_elements_by_css_selector('.bets.ml')` and `meci = item.find_elements_by_class_name('ml')`
Why should i be able to extract the `<h5></h5>` element and not the other elements?

Answer (score 0):

From your code block, its pretty clear you have just managed to cover up the real issue through `time.sleep(3)` as follows :

```
nume_liga = item.find_element_by_tag_name("h5").text
time.sleep(3)
    print('try', nume_liga)
```

While invoking `print()` for a text, I am not sure why `time.sleep(3)` was induced. So our main issue got covered up there. But as the `List` was already created, you are able to `print('try', nume_liga)`

But next, when you do `meci = item.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='bets ml']")` you face a **`StaleElementReferenceException`** because the **`HTML DOM`** have changed.

A closer look into the `<h5>` tag reveals it have a `onclick()` event as :

```
<h5 style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;" onclick="TodaysEventsLeagueWindow.minimizeRestoreClick(41410)">Europa League</h5>
```

A wild guess, while invoking `.text` on `<h5>` tag, the **`HTML DOM`** changes.

### Solution :

A possible solution with your current code block may be to use **`getAttribute("innerHTML")`** instead of `.text`. So your line of code will be :

```
nume_liga = item.find_element_by_tag_name("h5").get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'getAttribute`, I do not see the `HTML DOM` changing as that line of code passes,  the `time.sleep()` was left there as i tried all kinds of things

Comment: My bad :) check my updated Answer and update me the status.

Comment: now i get the `selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document` on the `nume_liga = item.find_element_by_tag_name("h5").get_attribute("innerHTML")` line